# Why compiler display error on one project, and not on the other for the same library CDMarkdownKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have two projects: FS and IL.

For both of them I use Xcode 11.5, Swift Language Version 4, cocoapod lib `CDMarkdownKit` and different Macbooks.

In *podfile.lock* there is the same version:

```
- CDMarkdownKit (1.2.1)
```

Now when I compile it on FS I got an error:

[image]

but on IL project everything compiles fine without error in the same place:

[image]

What makes the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me that in the first case you don’t handle the ‘default’ case into the switch, and that’s why the compiler tells you to be more exhaustive in handling all the cases. In the second case you actually have default: break, which does the trick. Handling all the cases or adding the fallback ‘default: break’ should do the job

Comment: You are right;( Now I wonder why there is a default case in the second, and in the first project there isn't

Comment: Same minimum target ios sdk? I assume you already tried, but maybe cleaning up both the projects, in case deleting all the derived data, might somehow help, up to running again pod install

Comment: No, it is not the same;( For project where it works I have 12.0 iOS Deployment Target, and where it doesnt work I have 10.0

Comment: Might it be due that? Maybe the way the pod file is co figured retrieves a different version of CDMarkdownKit. You could try to put the non working one to the same configuration of the working one, in terms of min iOS version ( and checking also the pod file configuration) to see if in such case it would install the actuall same versionbif CDMarkdownKit

Comment: There is the same version of CDMarkdownKit. I think that in repository where it works, someone added the change manually;) Some junior developer...  because when I do pod update the change with `defaulr break` disappear;) Voilaaa... there is no miracle;)

Comment: That I don’t know, could be, but if is only that the change should not be a problem to fix it :)